# Was homosexuality still illegal in Jammu and Kashmir when 377 was updated due to 370?

Tags: criminal-law, india, indian-penal-code, sexual-offences

When India updated [Section 377 IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_377_of_the_Indian_Penal_Code) and decriminalised homosexuality at that time Jammu and Kashmir still had [Article 370 of the Constitution of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_370_of_the_Constitution_of_India#:%7E:text=Article%20370%20of%20the%20Indian,and%20autonomy%20over%20the%20internal). Does or did the presence of Section 370 stop or halt the decriminalizing of homosexuality in the state?

Now Section 370 has been removed in the most controversial way, but I was asking the status before it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, J & K had to wait roughly 1 year more for decriminalisation of 377.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).